# What driver can I use to convert a 24 bit Parallel RGB signal into SPI or MCU?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, driver, lcd

I want to convert a 24 bit RGB signal into a SPI or MCU interface to drive a small LCD.
I have a circuit that I have created that has dedicated video memory and is connected to a small circuit that reads a small bit of program memory to draw sprites and graphics to a screen. It's inspired by my time playing with java script canvas drawing programs when I was in school. The program is read, the circuit outputs the image information layer-by-layer, and then sets a flag that enables the video memory to be read and sent to the screen.
For this purpose, I have designed and tested a device that connects to the video memory and sends it to a LCD screen in a 24 bit RGB parallel format(?). However, now that it's time to actually build everything, I can't for the life of me find a 24 bit parallel TFT/LCD screen in the correct resolution, but I can find screens that want the image data as SPI or MCU. So, is there any way to accomplish this, or is it as simple as desoldering the driver IC the screen comes with and just hooking it up directly? I have a lot more experience with digital logic than I do with this.

Comment: You mean like a parallel-to-serial converter? Or an FPGA? I doubt an MCU can keep up though.

Comment: What you're describing is an MCU with video capture capability. It's not a trivial task, and seems like you have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Rather explain what you're really trying to achieve overall.

Comment: You could add a simple R2R DAC to convert the signal into analog VGA video and send that to a computer monitor. (Pay attention to the blanking intervals and sync pulses, though - you might have to add more circuitry for that.)

Comment: DKNguyen, I think you may be correct. I'm not familliar with SPI or MCU interfaces for TFTs and LCDs, but a cursory look at their datasheets show that they have a reduced bus size, which leads me to believe that it wants it as serial

Comment: Thanks Jonathan S, I will look into that right away!